# Testing query speed in two different RDBMS

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, query-performance

I'm planning to compare the speed of queries in PostgreSQL and SQL server (on the same datasets). I was planning to run the same queries multiple times in both databases and use average response time in miliseconds as a rough estimate.

This seems a little too basic. Is there a better way to compare a speed of a query in two different database systems running on the same hardware? Any tools that I can use?

Comment: What's your criteria of "better"?

Comment: And you're likely to only end up measuring how the installation, queries and table designs align to the best practices of each RDBMS.  But check out HammerDB https://www.hammerdb.com/index.html

Comment: I think that, unless you master both DB plateform and are able to tune them, your comparaison could go on either side without really proving which one is "better".
Ex : Running multiple update and select queries on the same table on Oracle vs SQL with default config, will end way faster in Oracle, but if you turn on Read commited snapshot, then suddently the difference between both will change a lot. That's because Oracle uses optimistic locking by default with SQL uses pessimistic. There is a lot of tuning options and you want your test query to be optimise on each plateform before comparing

Comment: There are lies, damned lies, statistics and then there are [database benchmarks](https://www.google.com/search?q=There+are+lies%2C+damned+lies%2C+statistics+and+then+there+are+database+benchmarks&oq=There+are+lies%2C+damned+lies%2C+statistics+and+then+there+are+database+benchmarks&aqs=chrome..69i57.1174j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use HammerDB. With HammerDB you perform a TPC benchmark test. TPC benchmark testing can be used by vendors for official certification, but you can also use it as 'non-offical' for your personal benchmarking. The TPC-E (OLTP) and TPC-H (OLAP) are the more modern version of the TPC benchmark tests. With HammerDB you can emulate an OLAP or OLTP workload with the same characteristics (you can configure this) and run it on different RDBMSes.

You have 2 types of measurements; TPM and NOPM. TPM cannot be compared between different database types, but NOPM can. This tool is fairly easy to use, although you can make things a little more complex if you want to. :-) You can get HammerDB simpy from hammerdb.com.

Although this is not intended to test with a specific query, it could be usefull depending on your scenario.